# How to convert Date to timezone aware datetime in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Let's say I have

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "date": pl.Series(["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02"]).str.strptime(pl.Date), "%Y-%m-%d")
})
```

How do I localize that to a specific timezone and make it a datetime?

I tried:

```
df.select(pl.col('date').cast(pl.Datetime(time_zone='America/New_York')))
```

but that gives me

```
    shape: (2, 1)
    date
    datetime[μs, America/New_York]
    2021-12-31 19:00:00 EST
    2022-01-01 19:00:00 EST
```

so it looks like it's starting from the presumption that the naïve datetimes are UTC and then applying the conversion.  I set `os.environ['TZ']='America/New_York'` but I got the same result.

I looked through the polars config options in the API guide to see if there's something else to set but couldn't find anything about default timezone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of polars 0.16.3, you can do:

```py
df.select(
    pl.col('date').cast(pl.Datetime).dt.replace_time_zone("America/New_York")
)
```

In previous versions (after 0.14.24), the syntax was

```
df.select(
    pl.col('date').cast(pl.Datetime).dt.tz_localize("America/New_York")
)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
for i, j in zip(df.schema, df.dtypes) :
    if str(j) == "Datetime(time_unit='ns', time_zone='UTC')":
       df = df.with_columns(pl.col(i).dt.convert_time_zone('US/Eastern').apply(lambda s: str(s)[:19]))
    else:
       continue
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.